# Error using Ionic Devapp on Ionic version 4.10.3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic-devapp

I'm trying to use the devapp App on android but I'm getting the error

> ng run app:ionic-cordova-serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8100 --cordova-mock
>   [ng] Unknown option: '--cordova-mock'

[ERROR] ng has unexpectedly closed (exit code 1).

```
    The Ionic CLI will exit. Please check any output above for error details.
```

Any ideas? I'm using ionic version 4.10.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install lastest @ionic/angular-toolkit

Comment: Might seem a stupid question but how do I check what version I am on and how do I update it?

Comment: in your **package.json** file... npm i @ionic/angular-toolkit

Answer (score 0):

Try this if it doesn't work

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```